# PHP Line of code error

Tags: php

Okay so im trying to add my database name but it does the 'die' function

```
mysql_select_db("rfgd_20190375_db") or die("We are currently overloaded with users. Please try again in 1-5 minutes. Do not constantly refresh the page.");
```

My database name is rfgd_20190375_db

Comment: Instead of that message use error reporting (http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php). You also shouldnt be using `mysql_*` anymore. Use PDO or `mysqli_`.

Comment: mysql query function are deprecated now , use mysqli or pdoquery http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php , http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php

Comment: It would be better if SO provides code deprecation warning while posting code :)